# can not reference ToListAsync() inside my asp.net mvc4 + entity framework 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc4 web application + Entity framework 5. and i am trying to reference ToListAsync() as follow:-

```
var tservers = await t.TServers.Include(a => a.Technology.TechnologyIPs).Include(a => a.TVirtualMachines.Select(a2 => a2.Technology))
                   .Where(
           a2 => (!singlescan && String.IsNullOrEmpty(FQDN) && a2.TechnologyRole.Name.ToLower() == "hypervisor")
                 ||
                 (singlescan && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(FQDN) && a2.Technology.IT360ID == it360id)
                   ).ToListAsync();
```

but i keep receiving the following error :-

```
Error   10  'System.Linq.IQueryable<**.Models.**>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<**.Models.***>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C****\Repository.cs 181 22   Scanning
```

and i am including these references inside my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using T.ViewModels;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

What is the problem exactly? Is ToListAsync() available in EF 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's not. It was added in EF6.

Comment: and is the same applies for SaveChangesAsync() ?

Comment: Yep. All the async EF functions were introduced in 6. Previously it was sync only. Although, EF has yet to go the extra mile and actually allow truly async simultaneous queries, so each query is treated asynchronously, but multiple queries still must be run serially.

Comment: but in EF 5 i can use some Async methods such as DownloadStringTaskAsync & DownloadStringAsync ,, so seems some of the Async methods are avilable in EF 5 ? is this correct ?

Comment: Those are not EF methods. Yes, other areas of ASP.NET have had async support for some time. However, EF did not get async support until version 6.